# Core Data : crash when merge change, due to 'objc_msgSend'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

The last call `objc_msgSend` tells that it may be ***Zombie Messaged***, but it's in the Core Data library code...

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread: 1

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37a6ef78 objc_msgSend + 16
1 CoreData 0x3601a748 -[_CDSnapshot dealloc] + 60
2 CoreData 0x3601a336 -[_CDSnapshot release] + 118
3 CoreData 0x3601a6c4 _NSQLRow_dealloc_standard + 52
4 CoreData 0x3601a67c _PFfastRowRelease + 24
5 CoreFoundation 0x35692936 __CFDictionaryReleaseValue + 26
6 CoreFoundation 0x356e6104 __CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 96
7 CoreFoundation 0x3561a7e4 CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 2900
8 CoreFoundation 0x35619c60 CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 172
9 CoreData 0x3601a62e -[NSPersistentStoreCache decrementRefCountForObjectID:] + 66
10 CoreData 0x3601a5b0 -[NSSQLCore managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 124
11 CoreData 0x3601a4f6 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _informAffectedStoresOfInterestByChildContextInObjectsWithObjectIDs:withSelector:] + 414
12 CoreData 0x3601af34 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1800
13 CoreData 0x3606a1f6 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 2078
14 CoreData 0x36069092 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 182
15 Messenger -[WXManagedObjectContextManager managedObjectContextDidSave:] (in Messenger) (WXManagedObjectContextManager.m:106)
16 CoreFoundation 0x3562c1f4 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
17 Foundation 0x351f0740 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 344
18 CoreFoundation 0x356a1acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
19 CoreFoundation 0x356a1298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
20 CoreFoundation 0x356a003e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
21 CoreFoundation 0x3562349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
22 CoreFoundation 0x35623366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
23 GraphicsServices 0x372bf432 GSEventRunModal + 130
24 UIKit 0x3312fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
25 Messenger 0x000034fc 0x1000 + 9468
26 Messenger 0x00003468 0x1000 + 9320

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x35f733a8 kevent + 24
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3455df04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3455dc22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30
```

Answer (score 1):

May be its problem from begin so use any option from bellow ways..

1. set exception breakpoint in your application and for that follow this link [ios-5-xcode-backtrace](http://www.oramind.com/index.php/articles/182-ios-5-xcode-backtrace).

**OR**

2.Try to run the application with `NSZombieEnabled` from this link [how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) also

Comment: try any option otherwise see this link with many answer .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode hope its helpful to you mate... :)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to enable NSZombie option to detect Zombie Messaged problem. The real problem is that I can't reproduce the bug...

Comment: check out this link with answer http://superuser.com/questions/121857/how-do-i-fix-libdispatch-problem-crashing-mac-os-x-apps